# Error when compiling using Bosma in VS 2019 16.8.5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

When compiling in Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.5, with toolset v142, it throws the next error:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xmemory(230,12):
> error C2664:
> 'Bosma::EveryTask::EveryTask(std::chrono::system_clock::duration,std::function<void
> (void)> &&,bool)': cannot convert argument 2 from '_Ty' to
> 'std::function<void (void)> &&' 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
> _Ty=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &> 1>
> ] 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xmemory(228,1):
> message : Reason: cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'std::function<void
> (void)>' 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
> _Ty=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t &,bool),templateData_t &,sensorData_t &> 1>
> ] 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xmemory(230,33):
> message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can
> perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
> 1>Scheduler.h(37,9): message : see declaration of
> 'Bosma::EveryTask::EveryTask' 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\memory(1563):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void
> std::_Construct_in_place<_Ty,const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration&,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &>>(_Ty &,const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration &,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &> &&) noexcept(false)' being
> compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>            _Ty=Bosma::EveryTask
> 1>        ] 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\memory(2207):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation
> 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration&,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &>>(const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration &,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &> &&)' being compiled 1>
> with 1>        [ 1>            _Ty=Bosma::EveryTask 1>        ]
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\memory(2208):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation
> 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration&,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &>>(const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration &,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &> &&)' being compiled 1>
> with 1>        [ 1>            _Ty=Bosma::EveryTask 1>        ]
> 1>\External libraries\scheduler\Scheduler.h(132): message : see reference to
> function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptrBosma::EveryTask
> std::make_shared<Bosma::EveryTask,const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration&,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const sensorData_t
> &,bool),detail_t &,sensorData_t &>>(const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration &,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void
> (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t
> &,bool),templateData_t &,detail_t &> &&)' being compiled
> 1>serviceController.cpp(107):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void
> Bosma::Scheduler::every<void(__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const
> detail_t &,bool),templateData_t&,detail_t &>(const
> std::chrono::system_clock::duration,_Callable,templateData_t
> &,detail_t &)' being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
> _Callable=void (__cdecl &)(const templateData_t &,const detail_t &,bool) 1>        ]

As far I can understand, there is a problem with std::move. It was working flawlessly with previous version of VS :(

My functions have the following signatures:

```
void checkA (const templateData_t &templateData, const detail_t &detail, bool force = false);
```

And I do (minimal example):

```
class templateData_t {
//data and more data
};

class detail_t {
//data and more data
};

void checkA (const templateData_t &templateData, const detail_t &detail, bool force = false)
{
//blah blah
}



Bosma::Scheduler sched(16);
auto templateObject = getTemplate(...);
auto detail = getDetail(...);

sched.every(std::chrono::seconds(5), checkA, templateObject, detail);
```

Bosma::Scheduler::Every has the following signature:

```
void every(const Clock::duration time, _Callable &&f, _Args &&... args) {
  std::shared_ptr<Task> t = std::make_shared<EveryTask>
                                (time, std::bind(std::forward<_Callable>(f),
                                                 std::forward<_Args>(args)...));
  auto next_time = t->get_new_time();
  add_task(next_time, std::move(t));
}
```

And EveryTask:

```
EveryTask(Clock::duration time, 
          std::function<void()> &&f, 
          bool interval = false) 
          :
          Task(std::move(f), true, interval), time(time) {}
```

And Task:

```
explicit Task(std::function<void()> &&f, 
              bool recur = false, 
              bool interval = false) 
              :
              f(std::move(f)), recur(recur), interval(interval) {}
```

So, I think is something about conversion between lvalues and rvalues.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: please post a [mre]

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles!! Thank you for your answer:

class templateData_t {
//data and more data
};

class detail_t {
//data and more data
};

void checkA (const templateData_t &templateData, const detail_t &detail, bool force = false)
{
//blah blah
}



Bosma::Scheduler sched(16);
auto templateObject = getTemplate(...);
auto detail = getDetail(...);

sched.every(std::chrono::seconds(5), checkA, templateObject, detail);

Comment: Is Bosma a third-party library? This looks like a problem after the version update. If it is a third-party library, this should have something to do with it is not suitable for VS2019.

Comment: Yes @BarrnetChou, is a third-party library, but it was working flawlessly until the new update of VS